# android: SQL(query) error or missing database. (near "0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling:

Tags: android, sqlite

I know this question has been asked many times, but I cant find the issue when it comes to my code. PLEASE HELP

Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)                                                                        Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.                                                                          (near "0": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table course ( _id integer primary key autoincrement, title text not null, 0 text not null );)

CourseDBAdapter.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class CourseDBAdapter {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "course.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String COURSE_TABLE = "course";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
private static final String COLUMN_MARK = "0";

private String[] allColumns = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_MARK};

public static final String CREATE_TABLE_COURSE = "create table " + COURSE_TABLE + " ( "
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_MARK + " text not null " + ");";

private SQLiteDatabase sqlDB;
private Context context;
private CourseDBHelper courseDBHelper;

public CourseDBAdapter(Context cxt) {

    context = cxt;
}

public CourseDBAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException {

    courseDBHelper = new CourseDBHelper(context);
    sqlDB = courseDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    courseDBHelper.close();
}

public Course createCourse(String title) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);

    long insertId = sqlDB.insert(COURSE_TABLE, null, values);

    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(COURSE_TABLE, allColumns, COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId,
            null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Course newCourse = cursorToCourse(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newCourse;
}

public long deleteCourse(long idToDelete) {
    return sqlDB.delete(COURSE_TABLE, COLUMN_ID + " = " + idToDelete, null);

}

public long updateCourse(long idToUpdate, String newTitle) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, newTitle);

    return sqlDB.update(COURSE_TABLE, values, COLUMN_ID + " = " + idToUpdate, null);
}

public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses() {
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<Course>();

    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(COURSE_TABLE, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

    for (cursor.moveToLast(); !cursor.isBeforeFirst(); cursor.moveToPrevious()) {
        Course course = cursorToCourse(cursor);
        courses.add(course);

    }

    cursor.close();

    return courses;
}

public Course cursorToCourse(Cursor cursor) {
    Course newCourse = new Course(cursor.getLong(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    return newCourse;
}

private static class CourseDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    CourseDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COURSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w(CourseDBHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COURSE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String COURSE_TITLE = "com.example.diba.grade1.Identifier";
public static final String COURSE_ID = "com.example.diba.grade1.ID";
public static final String COURSE_MARK = "com.example.diba.grade1.MARK";
public static final String COURSE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD = "com.example.diba.grade1.Fragment_To_Load";
public static Context context;

// fixed number of well-known values in Java
public enum FragmentToLunch{VIEW, EDIT};

@Override // tells the compiler that the following method overrides a method of its superclass
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //saves current state of Activity | restores state when returned to Activity

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //super must be called when overriding | run your code in addition to the existing code in the onCreate()
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Set the activity content from a layout resource.
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); //A standard toolbar for use within application content.
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); //sets Toolbar to act as the ActionBar
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //Tool bar settings and options
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }else if(id == R.id.action_add_course){

        //Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications
        final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseDetailActivity.class);
        //creates alert dialog
        //(this) - Context: Interface to global information about an application environment
        final AlertDialog.Builder inputAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        inputAlert.setTitle("Add Course"); //setting alert dialog title

        //creating EditText Widget
        final EditText userInput = new EditText(this);
        //Setting view of EdiText on alert dialog
        inputAlert.setView(userInput);
        //Setting button values for alert dialog
        inputAlert.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
            {

                String userInputValue = userInput.getText().toString();

                //getBaseContext = access a Context from within another context
                CourseDBAdapter dbAdapter = new CourseDBAdapter(getBaseContext());

                dbAdapter.open();
                dbAdapter.createCourse(userInputValue);

                recreate();

                //putExtra = Add extended data to the intent.
                intent.putExtra(MainActivity.COURSE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD, FragmentToLunch.VIEW);
                startActivity(intent);

                dbAdapter.close();
            }
        });

        inputAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = inputAlert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    //calls parent method to run
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this one

```
private static final String COLUMN_MARK = "0";
```

Not sure a number is ok for a column name, you can try :

```
private static final String COLUMN_MARK = "mark";
```

Comment: Thank for the reply, but change it to what?

Comment: Thank you so much! It slightly works. But now i get the error "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:course.zero (code 1299)"

Comment: I changed the "0" to "zero"

Comment: Maybe you are trying to insert null in the zero column, double check

Comment: if needed to set to null, don't put not tull when creating the table in the zero column